# JQuery Mobile on PHP extension

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

This might seem a bit strange of a question but here it goes anyway.

Is there any reason why my JQuery Mobile pages couldn't have the .php extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it some weeks ago, and as far as I can remember it worked with no problem with php extension